# Trying to create a loop in SQL to count every time the agent Id shows up in different month it would count one more than the previous month

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to create a count where every time Agent Id shows up it would count one more than the previous month.

Image of end state:

[image: Image of end state]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by name order by d_month desc) cnt
from mytable t
```

Comment: This very close to what i'm looking for is there a way to get the newest d_moth.i'm getting the oldest to newest in the query ....Select*
     ,row_Number()over(partition by PERNR order by d_Month)cnt
     from  #CAREERADVANCE9